# Commenting out large sections of code in `.sty` files

Tags: expl3

`\begin{comment}...\end{comment}` is a useful device for commenting out large sections of text in the document environment. Unfortunately, using it for commenting out code sections inside the `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` environment in  `.sty` files produces incomprehensible compile errors. Is there any way to comment out sections of code other than by marking the beginning of each line with a `%` character? I find commenting out whole sections of code while de-bugging a tool I would not want to do without, especially when tracing unmatched braces `{}`, and doing this line by line is a sure way of introducing new typing errors.
No MWE for this one.

Comment: Without MWE, I would suggest: Use an editor that provides commenting blocks or regions. Or use `comment` and move the `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` into the `comment` environment.

Comment: one possibility is to temporarily remove the block of code, leaving a comment that you have done so, and move it to the end of the file, following `\endinput`.  the `\endinput` should cause (la)tex to stop reading the file, thus omitting the "transplanted" material.

Comment: any tex editor should be able to comment or uncomment a region with just a few keystrokes so placing a `%` on every line shouldn't be an issue really.  You can use `\iffalse...\fi` in some cases but can cause issue as you can not omit mismatched `fi` in that way.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Following your hint, within an `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` environment I am now using `...\ExplSyntaxOff\begin{comment}<CODE to be commented out>\end{comment}\ExplSyntaxOn...` and it works like a charm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.